# How to enable collision for dynamically generated sprites created using a constructor in Phaser?

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

The code goes something like this:

```
  function RainDrops(charLabel){
  this.xLocArray = [50, 120, 190, 260]; //Array for x pos 
  this.charLabel = charLabel;
  this.rainCreator = function(){
                                var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
                                this.genChar = game.add.sprite(this.xLocArray[x], 0, charLabel);
                                game.physics.arcade.enable(genChar);
                                genChar.body.gravity.y = 50;
                                genChar.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
                                };


}

function createChar(){
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
    switch(randomIndex){
        case 0:
            var Apple = new RainDrops('apple',uniqueRainDropId);
            Apple.rainCreator();
            break;
        case 1:
            var Candy = new RainDrops('candy',uniqueRainDropId);
            Candy.rainCreator();
            break;
        case 2:
            var Duck = new RainDrops('duck',uniqueRainDropId);
            Duck.rainCreator();
            break;
    }
}

function create(){
    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
    game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'backyard');
    var ground = game.add.sprite(40, game.world.height - 300, 'ground');
    ground.scale.setTo(0.7, 0.2);
    game.physics.arcade.enable(ground);
    ground.body.immovable = true;
    game.time.events.loop(500, createChar, this);

}

function update(){
    game.physics.arcade.collide(ground, ????);
}
```

I am new to javaScript and Phaser (and programming in general). I have been teaching myself js & phaser but I am stuck at this point. Now how do I tell the update function to check for collision since the sprites are being created dynamically. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [collide function](http://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.html#collide) in Phaser are designed to handle sprites and groups. So you can add your rain sprites to a `Phaser.Group` and then use that group in the collide call. Something like this:

```
function create() {
    var raingroup = game.add.group();
    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
    // etc.

function createChar() {
    //..
    Apple.rainCreator();
    raingroup.add(Apple);
    break;
    //etc. add Candy and Duck to group in same way

function update(){
    game.physics.arcade.collide(ground, raingroup, mycollisionHandler)
}

function mycollisionHandler(grnd, rainspr) {
    // note, parameters grnd and rainspr represent the sprites that have collided
    rainspr.kill();
}
```

Note that you can optionally use a processHandler to do additional checks and determine wether or not overlapping objects should collide. In your case I don't think you really need it, but just to show how that could work:

```
game.physics.arcade.collide(ground, raingroup, mycollisionHandler, myprocessHandler, this);
//..
function myprocessHandler(grnd, rain) {
    if (rain.health > 0) {
        return false; // no collisionHandler
    } else {
        return true; // will cause a call to collisionHandler
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! using group worked. And by the way, this was my first ever Stack Overflow question :)